# Why is Spring SAML preventing Spring OAuth2 from working?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2, spring-saml

I'm adding Spring SAML to some software that, until now, only used OAuth2. I need to make sure that OAuth still works, as SAML is only there for some of our customers.

I've run into an issue where the old oAuth seems to no longer work (though SAML is mostly ok). It seems that the Authentication Manager is being overwritten somehow, but it's not clear how or why. Here's the relevant code in my WebSecurityConfig.java:

```
@Override
protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordService.getEncoder())
            .and()
            .authenticationProvider(samlAuthenticationProvider)
            .authenticationProvider(oAuth2AuthenticationProvider());
}
```

And SAMLConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter() throws Exception {
    SAMLProcessingFilter samlWebSSOProcessingFilter = new SAMLProcessingFilter();
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationSuccessHandler(successRedirectHandler());
    samlWebSSOProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationFailureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
    return samlWebSSOProcessingFilter;
}

@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager() {
    return new ProviderManager(Collections.singletonList(samlAuthenticationProvider()));
}
```

Obviously, this is wrong, but it's unclear how to correct it.

When I debug, AuthenticationManagerBuilder.performBuild() is called three times on startup.

- First time builds one with SAML, OAuth2, and Dao AuthenticationProviders.
- Second builds one with an AnonymousAuthenticationProvider.
- Third builds one with another DaoAuthenticationProvider.

On login, the ProviderManager.authenticate() is called twice.

- First time, it only has one provider, the AnonymousAuthenticationProvider. This doesn't authenticate.
- Second time is the parent manager to the first time. It only has one provider, the SAMLAuthenticationProvider. If the user I'm authenticating with isn't found in SAML, this is still the last provider or manager to be called.

Why? How do I correct this so that I can either direct credentials to SAML in certain cases and OAuth in all other cases, or allow any credentials that don't work in SAML to overflow to OAuth?

Comment: You are registering a global `AuthenticationManager` through the `authenticationManager` method. You shouldn't be doing that.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok. Could you perhaps elaborate? I'm following several examples that do so.

Comment: See https://github.com/vdenotaris/spring-boot-security-saml-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/vdenotaris/spring/boot/security/saml/web/config/WebSecurityConfig.java. Your `SAMLConfig` should also extend the `WebSecurityCOnfiger` or even better you want to put it in a single `WebSecurityConfig` that way you can obtain the shared `authenticationManager`.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ok. What makes this approach correct? Part of my question involved a "why", as I like to understand rather than blindly follow. Perhaps this could be an answer?

Comment: The why is my first comment. You are providing your own global authentication manager which only contains the SAML authentication provider, this basically renders your `configure` of the `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` useless.

Comment: @M.Deinum Ah, I see. Why not post a more complete answer, rather than a fragmented one in comments?

Comment: @AlbeyAmakiir I am trying achieve similar kind of thing. DO you have any git link where i could refer to what you have achieved and how you solved it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `new ProviderManager()` creates an AuthenticationManager that skips the builder process, which is why it doesn't show up when debugging `performBuild()`.

The `authenticationManager()` bean method is intended to return the existing global AuthenticationManager, but the way the question uses it instead returns a new and different AuthenticationManager, overwriting what the builder returns. This is why it *does* show up when debugging `authenticate()`, and the built AuthenticationManager does not.

The solution is to pass the existing AuthenticationManager to `SAMLProcessingFilter.setAuthenticationManager()`, rather than a new one. The way I did this was to move all the code from SAMLConfig.java to WebSecurityConfig.java, which was more straightforward, but this is not the only way to do it.

Comment: Struck in a very similar problem. Can you share the configuration?